# Group By Issue converting MySQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I am trying to convert an old symfony 1.4 app from MySQL to PostgreSQL.

I keep running into the same issue over and over again.

I have some long joins and it is always complaining about having to have a Group By... and in some cases I add the Group By and it asks for another one.

I am new to postgres and I have absolutely no idea what is going on.

Here are the doctrine queries and error messages.

```
    public function getClassifieds($gs_id, $sort_param, $sorter) {

    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->select('a.*, u.*, t.*,ug.*,ur.*, avg(ur.rating) as rating ')
            ->from('Items a')
            ->leftJoin('a.MonitoredAds ma ON ma.item_id = a.id')
            ->leftJoin('a.GameCategories gc ON gc.game_id = a.game_id')
            ->leftJoin('a.User u ON u.id = a.user_id')
            ->leftJoin('u.Profile ug ON ug.user_id = u.id')
            ->leftJoin('a.UserRatings ur ON ug.user_id = ur.seller_id')
            ->where('a.game_server_id = ?', $gs_id)
            ->andWhere('a.quantity > ?', 0);
    switch ($sorter) {
        case 'datetime_oldest_to_newist':
            $q->orderBy('a.created_at asc');
            break;
        case 'datetime_newest_to_oldest':
            $q->orderBy('a.created_at desc');
            break;
        case 'price_lowest_to_highest':
            $q->orderBy('a.price + 0 ASC');
            break;
        case 'price_highest_to_lowest':
            $q->orderBy('a.price + 0 DESC');
            break;
        case 'quantity_lowest_to_highest';
            $q->orderBy('a.quantity asc');
            break;
        case 'quantity_highest_to_lowest';
            $q->orderBy('a.quantity desc');
            break;
        case 'quantity_highest_to_lowest';
            $q->orderBy('a.quantity desc');
            break;
        case 'sortby_usernameasc':
            $q->orderBy('u.username asc');
            break;
        case 'sortby_usernamedesc':
            $q->orderBy('u.username desc');
            break;
        case 'sortby_userstatus':
            $q->orderBy('ug.user_status asc');
            break;
    }

    return $q;
}
```

Gives Me this error message

SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "i.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT i.id AS i__id, i.featured AS i__featured, i.status AS...

So I change the code to ...

```
   ->andWhere('a.quantity > ?', 0)
        ->groupBy('a.id');
```

Then I get a new error...

SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "s.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ... AS i__created_at, i.updated_at AS i__updated_at, s.id AS s_...

I stopped here because this is changing the behaviour of the query in a major way and I really don't know what's going on.

I am not afraid of reading the docs but I don't even know where to start.

If you know what the issue could be please let me know. If you know where I should be looking in the docs please let me know that as well.

Thank you in advance.

Scott

Comment: MySQL is the exception, all other major RDBMS require queries using aggregate functions (such as AVG) group by all non-aggregated fields included in the results. The lack of a group by completely leads me to believe either the joined tables were in 1:1 relationship with `Items`, or the results for the non-aggregated fields were effectively near-random.

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct for PostgreSQL without `GROUP BY` all columns besides `ur.rating`:

```
->select('a.*, u.*, t.*,ug.*,ur.*, avg(ur.rating) as rating ')
```

Every selected and ordered column must be in `GROUP BY` or in agregate function.

For example, rewrite query:

```
 ->select('u.id, avg(ur.rating) as rating ')
 ...
 ->orderBy('u.id');
 ->groupBy('u.id');
```

Comment: Thank you. That gets rid of the error but the data from the other left joins are now missing. Are left joins not the same in Postgres?

Comment: I just have to read up on the joins. they appear to be quite a bit different